# NumbersOnly directive - Detect copy and paste keyboard combinations

Tags: angular, angular7

I have created an Angular directive to allows only numeric values in an input text box.  It works fine, however I cannot get it to detect the copy and paste keyboard shortcuts ctrl + c and ctrl + v.

In the code below in the onKeyDown HostListener, I think the checking should go in there.  I can add the checking with e.keyCode as follows :

```
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
```

but keyCode is now deprecated so need an alternative to this.  I have tried a hostListener  for ctrl + c and ctrl + v keys with EventEmitter's but I am not sure this is the approach to use.

Here is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[numbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

  private clipboardSanitisationRegex: RegExp = new RegExp(/[^0-9\.]/g);

  // Allow decimal numbers and negative values
  private allowableCharactersRegex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
  // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
  // Backspace, tab, end, home
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-' ];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    debugger;
    // Sanatize clipboard by removing any non-numeric input after pasting
    this.el.nativeElement.onpaste = (e:any) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let text;
      let clp = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData;
      if (clp === undefined || clp === null) {
        text = (<any>window).clipboardData.getData('text') || '';
        console.log('text = ' + text);
        if (text !== '') {
          text = text.replace(this.clipboardSanitisationRegex, '');
          if (window.getSelection) {
            let newNode = document.createElement('span');
            newNode.innerHTML = text;
            window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(newNode);
          } else {
            (<any>window).selection.createRange().pasteHTML(text);
          }
        }
      } else {
        text = clp.getData('text/plain') || '';
        if (text !== '') {
          text = text.replace(this.clipboardSanitisationRegex, '');
          document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
        }
      }
    };
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', [ '$event' ])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    debugger;
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.allowableCharactersRegex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use `event.key` and `event.code`

Comment: Ok jsut checked in my debugger, I could see that event.key is "Control" and code is "ControlLeft".  Which event.key and event.code combination should  I use?

Comment: `(e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true)` for copy

Comment: Thank you!! That worked.